# Material Icons not working via React-materialize

Tags: reactjs, materialize

I have a site using Middleman, Webpack and Materialize, we have a React component in one of the pages that works ok apart from the fact that Material Icons are not rendered on Internet Explorer and Firefox; all icons in the rest of the site work fine across all browsers.
Any help would be appreciated.

### Packages used

- materialize-css 0.100.2 => I tried 0.97, 0.98 with the same result
- webpack 3.10.0
- react 16.2.0 => I tried with 15.xx versions and got the same result
- react-materialize 1.1.1

In my `layout` I'm importing the icons according to the Docs

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="preload" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">`

what is being displayed at the moment is the icon name like `alarm_off` or `&#xE857;` as I've tried both input methods

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Material Design Icon isn't working on IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243432/material-design-icon-isnt-working-on-ie-11)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate causing this issue, as I mentioned above everything else works fine even on IE and Firefox, Material Icons as well but not in the React Component

Answer (score 2):

After reading lots of blogs and issues on GitHub, I managed to solved the problem thanks to [this Google issue](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/205), so I added this in my `style.scss`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Material Icons";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("Material Icons"),
       local("MaterialIcons-Regular"),
       url(https://rawgit.com/google/material-design-icons/master/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format("woff2"),
       url(https://rawgit.com/google/material-design-icons/master/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff) format("woff"),
       url(https://rawgit.com/google/material-design-icons/master/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: "Material Icons";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: ltr;

  /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

  /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;

  /* Support for Firefox. */
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

  /* Support for IE. */
  font-feature-settings: "liga";
}
```

Also, I updated this in my `nginx`

```
  location ~* \.(?:eot|otf|ttc|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
  expires 1M;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
```

Hope this help somebody else with similar issues.